# Symfony JMSSecurityExtrabundle override Controller wide PreAuthorize in Action

Tags: symfony

This is regarding Symfony 2.8 and the JMSSecurityExtrabundle, I use this to secure my whole Controller:

```
/**
 * @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
 */
class TestController extends Controller
{
```

This works nice but how can I now disable this for just specific actions in my controller?

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

Ok well, I found the answer myself. For these actions use the `@PreAuthorize("permitAll")` annotation.